# D8 - Access Webform submission values programatically

Tags: theming, 8, webforms

I have a webform whose results (some specific fields) I want to display in a table in a view. I am able to achieve that using the [Webform Views Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_views) module. The view displays the output as

```
<label>Field Name</label>
Field Value
```

I want it to be displayed as

```
<p>Field Value</p>
```

Although it can be done via CSS using `label{display:none;}`, is there any way to do it out of the box or using modules?

Also, I want to overwrite the default webform submission layout which I can achieve using the answer [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231141/how-to-override-webforms-submission-template-in-drupal-8). But when I try to access the elements of the webform submission using `{{html.fieldName}}` or `{{data.fieldName}}`, it again prints out the label with it. I tried the `nolabel` filter but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the patch from this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2901759).

Comment: This patch works perfectly when webform views are exposed to a table but when I override the template using TWIG file, it still shows with the label.

Comment: I recommend we move any discussion related to bugs into the Webform View Integration module's issue queue. https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_views